# Is there a consistent fix for when Outlook adds a vertical white line to an img in a table cell?

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, animated-gif

I keep trying all the fixes I could find either on here or Litmus, but none work. I have tried adding the `border-collapse: collapse;` attribute to no avail. I also tried setting **the line-height the same as the img height** but got the same result. All the images in email don't have that problem, only the row where I have two GIFS side by side is where the problem arise. The issue happens only on Outlook. When viewed on a browser the email renders fine.

Here is a snipbit from the HTML code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" class="row ee_columns two-cols ee_nostack ee_element" ee-type="container" data-title="Columns" style="max-width: 660px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); --darkreader-inline-bgcolor:#181a1b; table-layout: auto;" role="presentation" data-darkreader-inline-bgcolor="">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                          <tr>
                                                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="row-inner f-size-0 element-pad" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
                                                              
                                                              <!--[if mso]><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:660px;" width="660"><tr><td><![endif]--><div class="no-stack-column no-stack-column-width" ee-percent-width="50" style="max-width: 50%; min-width: 50%; width: 50%;">
                                                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: auto;" role="presentation">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                      <td dir="ltr" class="col-inner ee_dropzone" align="left"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="col-font-reset ee_element ee_imageelement" ee-type="element" data-title="Image" role="presentation" style="table-layout: auto;"><tbody><tr><td align="left" class="element-pad element-bord" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0px; font-size: 1px; line-height: 305px;"><a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/7/2/7/8/0/2/files/1239793_gif1.gif" width="330" alt="" style="width: 100%; display: block; max-width: 100%; min-height: auto; height: auto;" class="ee_editable" border="0"></a>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                                </table>
                                                              </div>
                                                              
                                                            <!--[if mso]></td><td align="left" valign="top" style="width:330px;" width="330"><![endif]--><div class="no-stack-column no-stack-column-width" style="max-width: 50%; min-width: 50%; width: 50%;" ee-percent-width="50">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: auto;" role="presentation"><tbody><tr>
                <td dir="ltr" class="col-inner ee_dropzone" align="left"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="col-font-reset ee_element ee_imageelement" ee-type="element" data-title="Image" role="presentation" style="table-layout: auto;"><tbody><tr><td align="left" class="element-pad element-bord" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0px; font-size: 1px; line-height: 305px;"><a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://i.emlfiles.com/cmpimg/7/2/7/8/0/2/files/1239794_gif2.gif" width="330" alt="" style="width: 100%; display: block; max-width: 100%; min-height: auto; height: auto;" class="ee_editable" border="0"></a>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
                    
                </td>
            </tr></tbody></table>
        </div><!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                                          </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                      </table>
```